# How to take only one element from foreach loop

Tags: .net-core

I have a problem, the code will display each item from the list, however, the user can delete only his own like. How can I improve the code so only one element from the list is displayed?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

cshtml:

```html
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @if (Model.MovieDetail.Likes.Any(x => x.UserId == (int.Parse(User.FindFirst("Id").Value))))
    {
        @foreach (var like in Model.MovieDetail.Likes)
        {
            @if (Model.MovieDetail.Likes.Any(x => x.UserId == like.UserId))
            {
                <a asp-controller="Likes" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@like.Id"><div><i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x" style="color:red;"></i><span style="color:red;"> @Convert.ToInt32(Model.MovieDetail.Likes.Count) </span></div></a>
            }
        }
    }
    @if (Model.MovieDetail.Likes.All(x => x.UserId != (int.Parse(User.FindFirst("Id").Value))))
    {
        <a asp-controller="Likes" asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@Model.MovieDetail.Id"><div id="the_heart"><i class="far fa-heart fa-2x" style="color:red;"></i><span style="color:red;">@Convert.ToInt32(Model.MovieDetail.Likes.Count)</span></div></a>
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i don't know why you have a loop in a loop when no matter what you'll output the same thing. And also: `else`

Comment: I was experimenting with a lot of lines of code. Eventually, I will refactor the code as soon it's working. desperate times :)

Comment: loops are definitely most of your problem. You are outputting one heart for every person that liked it.

Comment: The model itself has  List<MovieLikesModel> Likes. I'm not sure how can I otherwise get the like.id unless I list everything from Likes. This is my first project with .net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var like = Model.MovieDetail.Likes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == (int.Parse(User.FindFirst("Id").Value)));
    if (like != null)
    {
        <a asp-controller="Likes" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@like.Id"><div><i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x" style="color:red;"></i><span style="color:red;"> @Convert.ToInt32(Model.MovieDetail.Likes.Count) </span></div></a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a asp-controller="Likes" asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@Model.MovieDetail.Id"><div id="the_heart"><i class="far fa-heart fa-2x" style="color:red;"></i><span style="color:red;">@Convert.ToInt32(Model.MovieDetail.Likes.Count)</span></div></a>
    }
}
```

Running `.Any` to find a match on username is exactly the opposite of running `.All` that don't match. You don't need to test it twice, let alone n + 2 times as you were doing.

Comment: This was my first attempt, but the problem remains. When I click on add 'Like', again two hearts like the image are showing :\

Comment: no, not with the `else`. It's impossible. Although I think there is a problem with getting the `id` to remove. I'll make a change

Comment: You are amazing! I didn't know it's possible to declare variables in cshtml. Thank you very much! x 1000

Comment: you can inside a @{} block, which includes the @if block. You should only need the @ on the outermost code loop. But I didn't test all the syntax